# NgFor display last element

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have array of objects

```
[0: {yplace: 11, xrow: 4}1: {yplace: 12, xrow: 4}2: {yplace: 13, xrow: 4} ]

<div class="row-place" *ngFor="let seat of reservation.seats; let i = index" >
  {{seat.xrow}} <input [(ngModel)]="seat.xrow" name="row" type="number" min="0" class="place form-control signup-row">
  {{seat.yplace}} <input [(ngModel)]="seat.yplace" name="place" type="number" min="0" class="place form-control signup-row">
</div>
```

And in html i have 3 inputs, all bind only last element from array?

but when i use `{{seat.xrow}}` and `{{seat.yplace}}` that display fine that i expected

How do two-way data binding with input tag. Each input has unique index from array not last element?

edit: 
and i have that

```
  reservation: ReservationAdminDto = {
    seats: [],
    email: '',
    phoneNr: ''
 };
```

**ReservationAdminDto.model.ts** has a form:

```
export class ReservationAdminDto {
  email: string;
  phoneNr: string;
  seats: SeatDto[];
}
```

**SeatDto.model.ts**

```
export class SeatDto {

  xrow: number;
  yplace: number;

  constructor (
    xrow: number,
    yplace: number,
  ) {
    this.xrow = xrow;
    this.yplace = yplace;
  }
}
```

Comment: I copy output this output from console.log this is only array of object. Each element in array have form {yplace: nr, xrow: nr}

Comment: looks perfect to me : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ecsj3?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts what isn't working ?

Comment: The stackblitz provided by @Stavm is working fine. what is the issue? Can you explain more!!!

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT i must check it, i have same data and html that example created by Stavm

Comment: Probably not the same version of Angular though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `*ngFor` loop is probably inside a `form` tag. Since the input elements in the loop have the same name, they display the last value in the array, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ecsj3-eiyuzz).

To bind the correct item values, make sure that the input names are unique by appending the loop index to each name (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ecsj3-yzfwbu)):

```
<div class="row-place" *ngFor="let seat of reservation.seats; let i = index" >
  <input [(ngModel)]="seat.xrow" [name]="'row'+i" type="number" min="0" class="place form-control signup-row">
  <input [(ngModel)]="seat.yplace" [name]="'place'+i" type="number" min="0" class="place form-control signup-row">
</div>
```

Comment: It's work fine, and i also use name without [ ]. What is diff between [name] and name?

Comment: The `[name]` notation is for property binding. The index can also be appended to the name with interpolation: `name="row{{i}}"`. The two techniques allow `i` to be replaced by its value instead of being interpreted as the string "i".

Comment: @ConnorsFan : value of `i` is always last index, any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a tracking issue : `[(ngModel)]` creates new variables, and it can't bind to object properties properly. use a custom track by function to get a grip on it :

```html
<div class="row-place" *ngFor="let seat of reservation.seats; let i = index; trackBy: customTB">
```

```js
customTB(index, item) {
  return `${index}-${item.xrow}-${item.yplace}`
}
```

Comment: Can you check my question i add edit section and describe my model

Comment: Not really useful. Did you try what I wrote down in my answer ?

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: I create object reservation and when i console.log(reservation.seat) i have output empty array without type SeatDto